# Is it possible to create an MDI window to the dialog-based window instead of the frame window?

Tags: c++, winapi

I know you can create an MDI window to Frame window but what about dialog-based window is it possible to create MDI window to it too or it is just exclusive for Frame window only?

[image]

or Is it possible to create an MDI client window then create an MDI child Frame window to dialog-based window?

Comment: I think your diagram is correct. I don't know of a way to substitute a dialog for the Main Frame window, because it has specific behaviors for supporting MDI Child windows.

Comment: If you want to have your dialog as an MDI child, then yes - you can! Sort of. You can create the MDI child frame in the usual way but define its View Window as being derived from CFormView (of which see the documentation, but it's a scrolling view based on a dialog template resource). Never tried it myself but, if you do, let us know jhow you get on.

Comment: Can you clarify, are you using MFC or plain winapi?

Comment: Yes but your image is a MFC application which is why I was unsure.

Comment: Well, it is still not clear to me if you A) Want to host a MDI client window (and child frames) inside a dialog main frame, or B) Want dialog based MDI child frames in the MDI client frame.

Comment: @Anders: "A" is What I want.

Comment: in what problem create your mdi frame window as child window inside dialog ?

Comment: @RbMm: Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: i mean that this is very easy - what prevent create you or frame window (for which you call `DefFrameProc` ) as child of your dialog ? or even direct `"MDICLIENT"` inside dialog without frame ?

Comment: @RbMm: Could you give me a topic link talking about that or is possible write me an example to understand well?

Comment: but are you try do this itself ? are you know how create MDI frame, client and child ? i not view here any problems (except - for what this need ?)

Comment: @RbMm: No, I know how to create a frame, dialog-based window, and MID child to frame window. that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Can it be done? Probably. Is it a good idea? Probably not.

The main issue is that both MDI and dialogs want to control focus and keyboard handling.

You definitely need to use `CreateDialog` and not `DialogBox` to create the main window because you need control of the message loop. `TranslateMDISysAccel` and `IsDialogMessage` can help you a little bit but you probably need some custom handling that determines if the active/focused window is a MDI child frame or a normal dialog control and prioritize messages for MDI or the dialog. The most difficult being tabbing out of the MDI child frame window and back into the dialog. The last one you could work around by adding a custom key like <kbd>F6</kbd> to set the focus back to the dialog.

Raymond Chen did a [blog post series](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-US?rq=site%3Ablogs.msdn.microsoft.com%2Foldnewthing&rn=oldnewthing&query=dialog) about dialogs, some of them about how you can write your own dialog class and/or [custom dlgproc handling](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031113-00/?p=41843).

Even with full control of the message loop and some control over the dialog, you might still end up having to subclass the dialog and/or the MDI client window to handle specific messages.